# Handle Horizontal Scroll view for R To L languages

Tags: scrollview, locale, android, horizontalscrollview

How to handle Horizontal scroll view for R to L languages.
I am adding 24 Linear Layout in Horizontal scroll view.It is working for L to R, But for not R to L languages.
XML Code :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTimeAmPm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout0Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout10Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11Am"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout0Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout10Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11Pm"
            layout="@layout/include_time_textview" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is working in L to R languages.But in R to L Languages, It show like 
[image]

It is Scrolling from Left to Right Direction, But only 4 Layouts added in Scroll view.After Scrolling from Left to Right --->
[image]

I want to add 24 layouts in Horizontal Scroll view and Scroll view direction should be from Right to left (When R to L language is selected).

Comment: try listview.setSelecion(youtlist.size()-1);

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: any luck with that ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on devices with api 17. accidentally I tried this and worked fine for me:
I just put `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` in HorizontalScrollView tag and `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` for every children of it (your LinearLayout)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id = "@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTimeAmPm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="A"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="B"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="C"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="D"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="E"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="F"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="G"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="H"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="I"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="J"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="K"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

and in you class onCreate add

```
final HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                hsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        }, 100L);
```

This is the sample done by me which is working absolutely fine

Comment: It is not Working for R to L language.I tested this code on Arabic Language. It is working only for English(L to R) language.

Comment: Can you post your code?? or any of the arabic thing you used?

Comment: I replaced english alphabets with ص and س everything working fine.

Comment: I am adding android:supportsRtl="true" in Manifest file and change the language to Arabic. After that, I run apk. Arabic is R to L language. So scroll direction should be Right to Left.

Answer (score 0):

oh your java code must simiular this :

```
final HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                hsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        }, 100L);
```

and your xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvcustomer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same Issue all I did was instead of rtl.!
i treid this and it works perfectly fine for me.!

```
 android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```